# How to find smallest value with range of floats (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, range, min

I have a math problem where I substitute x with numbers from 1 to 25. I did this using a for loop with x in range(1,26). This prints out a list of floats, as it should. After that, I am supposed to print the smallest number found between this range. I have tried using "min()" but I get an error saying that float object is not iterable. Can someone help me figure out a way to print the smallest value?

Comment: *please don't explain your code* - instead, post it. also, read what `min` does.

Answer (score 1):

Min() takes a list, not a float. You don't need a for loop.

```
myNums = [1.234, 2.345, 4.543]
print min(myNums)
```

Otherwise if for your math problem you have to use a loop:

```
myNums = [1.234, 2.345, 4.543]
min = myNums[0] #initial low
for num in myNums:
    if num < min:
        min = num
print min
```